# Qt: Compile your code with -fPIC or -fPIE

Tags: qt, cmake, position-independent-code

```
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1079:4: error: #error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. " "Compile your code with -fPIC or -fPIE."
```

It seems all the components are being read correctly but there is this error which pops up. What do I need to change in CMAKE to correct this?

I put these lines into `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
   ${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
```

but this doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Did you understand the error message?

Comment: add_definitions(-fPIC)

Answer (score 2):

You need to build your target as position independent code. You can do this in a compiler-agnostic way by using the [`POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE.html).

> The `POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE` property determines whether position independent executables or shared libraries will be created. This property is True by default for `SHARED` and `MODULE` library targets and `False` otherwise. This property is initialized by the value of the `CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE` variable if it is set when a target is created.

target property like so:

```
set_target_properties(your_target_name PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE TRUE)
```

Note: [position independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code):

> In computing, position-independent code (PIC) or position-independent executable (PIE) is a body of machine code that, being placed somewhere in the primary memory, executes properly regardless of its absolute address. PIC is commonly used for shared libraries, so that the same library code can be loaded in a location in each program address space where it does not overlap with other memory in use (for example, other shared libraries).

Comment: How can this setting be used with QMAKE ?  (Qt5)