# Why -fPIC must be provided as definition, rather than compiler flag

Tags: cmake, qt5

In my CmakeLists.txt file I have had the line

```
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC -Wall")
```

and with that, I run into the error

```
"You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. " "Compile your code with -fPIC (-fPIE is not enough)."
```

Then I accidentally found topic

[Error while compiling QT project in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978608/error-while-compiling-qt-project-in-cmake)

where it was suggested to add the line

```
add_definitions(-fPIC)
```

And really, it seems to work. I have two questions:

1./ Is something wrong with the first form of defining PIC? (or, why they have different effect?)

2./ I did "reprocess" that line from and older project, where it worked fine. What could change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `add_definitions(-fPIC)` is wrong. First, it should be `add_compile_options`. Then, `add_definition` is a directory command which you should avoid.

CMake must detect that the macro name starts with `-f` and add it as compiler option instead.

What you really want is to tell CMake that a target should be compiled as position independent code.

```
set_target_properties(your-executable PROPERTIES
    POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON
)
```

That should do the trick and is compiler agnostic.

Comment: Alternatively, `set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)` will set the property for all targets in your directory and subdirectories.

Comment: Maybe a comment to the misleading link would be useful, to prevent questions like this one.